# Form with editable elements should have `editable-form` attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I have a form within which i have used `x-editable` plugin for editing a text-field. But i am getting the following script error. Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

```
Form with editable elements should have `editable-form` attribute. <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="textBtnForm" class="ng-scope ng-binding editable">
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yu8rG/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <form action="#" > 
        <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="textBtnForm">
    {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
        </span>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">edit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["xeditable"]);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "manu";
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'awesome user'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things to do:

1. add the `editable-form` attribute to the form as the error suggest.
2. remove the `e-form="textBtnForm"`, it's not required for your requirement.
3. instead, set the `textBtnForm` as a name of the form.
4. add `type="button"` to the edit button, otherwise it doesn't work (don't know why ..).
5. I've also add save and cancel button when editing for the sake of completeness.

The result would look like this:

```
<form editable-form name="textBtnForm" action="#"> 
    <span editable-text="user.name">
        {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
        edit
    </button>
    <span ng-show="textBtnForm.$visible">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="textBtnForm.$waiting">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="textBtnForm.$waiting" ng-click="textBtnForm.$cancel()">
          Cancel
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5TZX5/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but the real issue Is that see in my actual application there is a main form in which there are three grids. ..and I am using xeditable form with row edit for the three grid....and finnally these three grids will be within the main form.....when we include within this main form the xeditable wont work....for example enclose another form tag across the above which you have shown it wont work I guess...

Comment: Then please show a part of your actual application that represent the problem. We could start from there to find if it is possible or not.

Comment: I found that only the first innner form does not work, then I just add an empty form at the top and it's all working! as least in Chrome. Not sure if this workaround will work cross browser since the nested `form` isn't a valid HTML5. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw4y9/

Comment: Another solution is to use `ng-form` attribute instead and do the submision manually by `textBtnForm.$submit()` when clicking a save button. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8zL7/1/

Answer (score 1):

If there is just a single element you want to edit, you can remove the form, which will make it work.
Or you must add `ng-click="$form.$show()"` to the `span` element as described [here](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/6).

Comment: any suggestion regarding with that

Comment: Yeah, you can (or should) remove the form. Then it works, just tested it in your Fiddle. Updated my answer

Comment: since my ui has already a form which does another action.... inside that form i need to place this xeditable textfield

Comment: I see. If you add ng-click="$form.$show()" it stars to your span, it starts to work. Found it here: https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/6

Comment: Updated the answer once more :) Does it work for you with that ng-click?

Comment: see this is my original working jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/55GEL/) which does not have any form... but when i add `ng-click="$form.$show()"` to the `span` (http://jsfiddle.net/6SUAn/) functionality is changed

Comment: I am afraid you can't combine e-form attribute with form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58171/discussion-between-alex-man-and-david-bohunek).

Answer (score 0):

the previous approach is partial correct and can be applied only if use a single input in that form. Also if you try to add more elements, then will not work correct. 
So the right solution that i have is to use ng-form with editable-form directive as block for each form element (input) that you want apply the xedit plugin, and of course remove editable-form from main form.

the sample based by your code is below:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
  <form action="#" >
    <div ng-form editable-form name="textBtnForm">
      <span editable-text="user.name" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()">{{user.name||'empty'}}</span>
      <span ng-show="textBtnForm.$visible">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="textBtnForm.$waiting" ng-click="textBtnForm.$submit()">              Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="textBtnForm.$waiting" ng-click="textBtnForm.$cancel()">cancel</button>
    </span>
    </div>

    <hr>second form element<hr>

    <div ng-form editable-form name="textBtnForm2"> 
      <span editable-text="user.phone" ng-click="textBtnForm2.$show()">{{ user.phone || 'empty' }}</span>
      <span ng-show="textBtnForm2.$visible">
        <button type="button" ng-disabled="textBtnForm2.$waiting" ng-click="textBtnForm2.$submit()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="textBtnForm2.$waiting" ng-click="textBtnForm2.$cancel()">  Cancel</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```