# Single edit hyperlink option for all the field edits

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an application in AngularJS with edit, save and cancel options, the application is working fine, right now i am having edit option for all the three fields, but how can i have a single edit option for making all the fields editable and save and cancel similarly

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Gxa/)**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl">
    <h2>Editors</h2>
    <span ng-repeat="location in locations">


    <div class="field">
        <strong>State:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.state"><input ng-model="location.state"/></div>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
        <strong>City:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.city">
            <select ng-model="location.city" ng-options="loc.city as loc.city for loc in selectableCities"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <strong>Neighbourhood:</strong>
        <div click-to-edit="location.neighbourhood"><input ng-model="location.neighbourhood"/></div>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>


    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of implementing your own directive, consider using a [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form) module to achieve what you want.

Comment: since xeditable has some drawback that is when i used the xeditable form edit within another form it wont work, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996429/form-with-editable-elements-should-have-editable-form-attribute

Comment: @runTarm do you have any suggestion for this SO question

Comment: I've answered the question in your comment above, please try to see if it works or not.

Comment: without xeditable can't we do this....

Answer (score 0):

I created a new directive that uses you directive. Also i updated your directive a bit. 
Not sure if you wanted this.

you can find the jsFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/n7Gxa/12/).

updated your directive so that it does not show individual save n cancel when in edit all mode.

you can find the **updated jsFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/n7Gxa/17/)**.

```
    app.directive("clickToEditAll",function(){
    var partial = '<div><div class="field">' +
        '<strong>State:</strong>' +
        '<div click-to-edit="myData.state" external-controle="externalControle"><input ng-model="myData.state"/></div>' +
   ' </div>' +


    '<div class="field">' +
        '<strong>City:</strong>' +
        '<div click-to-edit="myData.city" external-controle="externalControle">' +
            '<select ng-model="myData.city" ng-options="loc.city as loc.city for loc in selectableCities"></select>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="field">' +
        '<strong>Neighbourhood:</strong>' +
        '<div click-to-edit="myData.neighbourhood" external-controle="externalControle"><input ng-model="myData.neighbourhood"/></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<button ng-show="externalControle.editAll !== true" ng-click="editAllClicked()">Edit All</button><button ng-show="externalControle.editAll === true" ng-click="saveAllClicked()">Save</button><button ng-show="externalControle.editAll === true" ng-click="cancelAllClicked()">Cancel</button><hr/></div>'
    var retValue = {
        restrict: "A",
        template:partial,
        scope:{
            myData:"=",
            selectableCities:"=",
            externalControle: "="
        },
        link:function(scope, elements, attributes){
            scope.editAllClicked = function(){
                scope.externalControle.editAll = true;
            }

            scope.saveAllClicked = function(){
                scope.externalControle.saveAll = true;
            }

            scope.cancelAllClicked = function(){
                scope.externalControle.cancelAll = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return retValue;
});
```

Comment: click Edit All button change city to kollam and then click the Cancel button...you can see the city not changing to previous since we are cancelling it

Comment: updated the jsfiddle so that click-to-edit directive does not show save n cance in edit all mode. I have edited my answer to include the new link. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/n7Gxa/13/)

Comment: still the cancel button after changing the city name is having issues

Comment: hey sorry i checked and updated the code again. I think this should fulfill your requirements. http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/n7Gxa/15/

Comment: thanks....but issues are still there....check this out---> click city hyperlink edit->change to kollam->dont click save hyperlink->click Edit All button->then click Cancel button-> city not changed to previous

Comment: Another version. hope all the kinks have been removed. http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/n7Gxa/17/